# error when installing rocon on turtlebot

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying installing turtlebot on my PC. And  actually I follow the tips on roswiki.

Unfortunately ,when I create a workspace for rocon and then I run command

```
$ wstool init -j5 src https://raw.github.com/robotics-in-concert/rocon/indigo/rocon.rosinstall
```

Then i got an Error which said `404 Error`.

Now im wondering if this web doesn't exist any more. If it does, how can I download rocon package. thx

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246726/error-when-installing-rocon-on-turtlebot/) by [EdisonJava](https://answers.ros.org/users/28382/edisonjava/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-10-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-29**:
Could I ask you to please spend some time formatting your text properly next time? As it was, it was rather unreadable. Thanks.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-29**:
And could you please also include links to any tutorials you are following? Without those it's rather difficult to know what you have been trying to do.

Thanks.

**Comment by [EdisonJava](https://answers.ros.org/users/28382/edisonjava/) on 2016-10-30**:\

1. http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/indigo/Source%20Installation
   above is the link that I followed to try to install turtlebot. The command that goes wrong is in the"0.0.2 Worksapce", thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the same error as you. The path of rocon-indigo has changed on github. So you can use the following command:

> wstool init -j4 src https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robotics-in-concert/rocon/release/indigo/rocon.rosinstall

---

Originally posted by [potato](https://answers.ros.org/users/28518/potato/) with karma: 16 on 2016-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EdisonJava](https://answers.ros.org/users/28382/edisonjava/) on 2017-08-15**:
谢谢你啦啦啦啦啦啦啦

**Comment by [captainyao](https://answers.ros.org/users/34060/captainyao/) on 2018-03-08**:
excuse me,I have the same problem when I installed kobuki,so have the path of kobuki and turtlebot changed?